# Using YAGO Corpus for taxonomy

Tags: dataset, nlp, taxonomy

Hi I am trying to get taxonomy of given word and came across yago.Can anyone explain how to use yago for taxonomy of given sentence preferably with python.

Comment: what do you mean with a taxonomy of a word/ sentence. YAGO offers taxonomy for the entities registered such as people, organisations, ..etc. Can you give an example for your target.

Comment: Try: https://github.com/bowdenk7/yago and https://github.com/yago-naga/aida

Comment: Thanks for help.I am trying out the libraries at github.